# In Romans 13:11-12 why such a sense of urgency?

Tags: romans

> [Rom 13:11-12 NLT] (11) This is all the more urgent, for you know how late it is; time is running out. Wake up, for our salvation is nearer now than when we first believed. (12) The night is almost gone; the day of salvation will soon be here. So remove your dark deeds like dirty clothes, and put on the shining armor of right living.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Jesus had taught that the judgment of the Jewish theocracy based in Jerusalem was to fall upon the then current generation:

> [Mat 23:32-38 ESV] (32) Fill up, then, the measure of your fathers. (33) You serpents, you brood of vipers, how are you to escape being sentenced to hell? (34) Therefore I send you prophets and wise men and scribes, some of whom you will kill and crucify, and some you will flog in your synagogues and persecute from town to town, (35) so that on you may come all the righteous blood shed on earth, from the blood of righteous Abel to the blood of Zechariah the son of Barachiah, whom you murdered between the sanctuary and the altar. (36) Truly, I say to you, all these things will come upon this generation. (37) "O Jerusalem, Jerusalem, the city that kills the prophets and stones those who are sent to it! How often would I have gathered your children together as a hen gathers her brood under her wings, and you were not willing! (38) See, your house is left to you desolate.

So they knew it was to occur very, very soon:

> [1Pe 4:17 NKJV] (17) For the time has come for judgment to begin at the house of God; and if it begins with us first, what will be the end of those who do not obey the gospel of God?
>
> [1Jo 2:18 NKJV] (18) Little children, it is the last hour; and as you have heard that the Antichrist is coming, even now many antichrists have come, by which we know that it is the last hour.

Revelation also shows that it was all to go down very quickly:

> [Rev 1:1, 3 NKJV] (1) The Revelation of Jesus Christ, which God gave Him to show His servants--things which must shortly take place. And He sent and signified it by His angel to His servant John, ... (3) Blessed is he who reads and those who hear the words of this prophecy, and keep those things which are written in it; for the time is near.

Answer (score 0):

“For man is as a vapor that appears and is gone” The Word emphasizes the fleeting time of our lives. The Apostles could see time flying and the urgency of every soul, then as now, to seek God while opportunity affords.  Bless you.

Comment: We're [looking for long answers](http://meta.hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/a/533/) that provide some explanation and context. Don't just give a one-line answer; explain why your answer is right, ideally with citations. Answers that don't include explanations may be removed. Please [edit your answer](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/posts/39929/edit) to add explanation and citations to reliable sources that support the assertions made here, otherwise it's in danger of being deleted.